# Integrating PHP into Javascript to display map markers with Google API

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am getting one map marker to display but not multiple markers. However the data displays in the HTML log. I think I am missing a loop or did not use my current loop correctly. Anyone who could clarify would make my day. Thank you. Herewith the code:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Find a store</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
    function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -28.5758488, lng: 25.1128267},
            zoom: 5
        });
        setMarkers(map);
};
```

```
    <div id="map"></div>

<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'store', array("output"=>"raw"), 'posts_per_page' => 50,);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<?php $lat = types_render_field("lat", array("output"=>"raw")); ?>
<?php $long = types_render_field("long", array("output"=>"raw")); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var lat = <?php echo $lat; ?>;
    var long = <?php echo $long; ?>;
    var locations = [
        ['<?php the_title(); ?>', lat, long]
    ];

    function setMarkers(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var location = locations[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: location[1], lng: location[2]},
                map: map,
                title: location[0],
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the output script within the console log:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -28.5758488, lng: 25.1128267},
    zoom: 5
    });
setMarkers(map);
};
```

```
    <div id="map"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setMarkers(map) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -25.746111, lng: 28.188056}),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Willow Way Spar'
                });
            }
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setMarkers(map) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -29.919885, lng: 30.941782}),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Yellowwood park Superspar'
                });
            }
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setMarkers(map) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -26.8598225, lng: 26.6317514}),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Zest for Health'
                });
            }
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setMarkers(map) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -25.8299422, lng: 28.2819103}),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Zest Wellness Centre'
                });
            }
    </script>
```

...and I get the same result with this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- Row for main content area -->
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns" id="content" role="main">

<h1 class="entry-title">Find a store</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
    function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -28.5758488, lng: 25.1128267},
            zoom: 5
        });
        setMarkers(map);
};
```

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'store', array("output"=>"raw"), 'posts_per_page' => 50,);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<?php $lat = types_render_field("lat", array("output"=>"raw")); ?>
<?php $long = types_render_field("long", array("output"=>"raw")); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var lat = <?php echo $lat; ?>;
    var long = <?php echo $long; ?>;
</script>

    <script>
        function setMarkers(map) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: lat, lng: long},
                    map: map,
                    title: '<?php the_title(); ?>',
                });
            }
    </script>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Herewith a link to the test page:
http://www.golonutrition.co.za/find-a-store/

With your help Dan, I tried using it like this but obviously I am missing the point somewhere...

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Row for main content area -->
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns" id="content" role="main">

<h1 class="entry-title">Find a store</h1>

<?php
    $storeData = [];

    foreach ( $loop->posts as $post ) {
            $storeData[] = [
                    'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
                    'lat'   => types_render_field('lat', array('output'=>'raw')),
                    'long'  => types_render_field('long', array('output'=>'raw'))
            ];
    }

    wp_localize_script('jquery-core', 'storeData', $storeData);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
        function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -28.5758488, lng: 25.1128267},
                zoom: 5
            });
            setMarkers(map);
    };
</script>

        <div id="map"></div>

    <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'store', array("output"=>"raw"));
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>

    <?php $lat = types_render_field("lat", array("output"=>"raw")); ?>
    <?php $long = types_render_field("long", array("output"=>"raw")); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setMarkers(map) {
        for (var i=0; i<i; i++) {
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: storeData[i].lat, lng: storeData[i].long}),
                    map: map,
                    title: storeData[i].title
            });
    }
}
    </script>

<?php endwhile; ?>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/..." async defer></script>

</div>
```

The updated code as per Dan. (Although still one small error: InvalidValueError: in property lat: not a number)

```
<?php
$storeData = [];
$args = array('post_type' => 'store');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
foreach ( $loop->posts as $post ) {
    $storeData[] = [
        'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
        'lat'   => types_render_field('lat', array('output'=>'raw')),
        'long'  => types_render_field('long', array('output'=>'raw'))
    ];
}
wp_localize_script('jquery-core', 'storeData', $storeData);?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Row for main content area -->
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns" id="content" role="main">

<h1 class="entry-title">Find a store</h1>

<div id="map"></div>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/..." async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -28.5758488, lng: 25.1128267},
            zoom: 5
        });
        var j = storeData.length;
        for (var i=0; i<j; i++) {
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: storeData[i].lat, lng: storeData[i].long}),
                map: map,
                title: storeData[i].title
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update 2:

```
<?php
$storeData = [];
$args = ['post_type' => 'store'];
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
foreach ($loop->posts as $post) {
    $storeData[] = [
        'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
        'lat' => types_render_field('lat', ['output' => 'raw']),
        'long' => types_render_field('long', ['output' => 'raw']),
    ];
}
wp_localize_script('jquery-core', 'storeData', $storeData);
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Row for main content area -->
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns" id="content" role="main">

<h1 class="entry-title">Find a store</h1>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB2ealUwmPEEdwZXFBAAcc7tiQLAl-Tys4&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.2758488, 26.1128267),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        var j = storeData.length;
        function initMap() {
            for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(storeData[i].lat, storeData[i].long),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(storeData[i].title);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        };
    </script>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

#### Update 1:

This is all you need:

```
<?php
$storeData = [];
$args = array('post_type' => 'store');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
foreach ( $loop->posts as $post ) {
    $storeData[] = [
        'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
        'lat'   => types_render_field('lat', array('output'=>'raw')),
        'long'  => types_render_field('long', array('output'=>'raw'))
    ];
}
wp_localize_script('jquery-core', 'storeData', $storeData);
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Row for main content area -->
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns" id="content" role="main">

<h1 class="entry-title">Find a store</h1>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/..." async defer></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -28.5758488, lng: 25.1128267},
                zoom: 5
            });
            var j = storeData.length;
            for (var i=0; i<j; i++) {
                var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: storeData[i].lat, lng: storeData[i].long}),
                    map: map,
                    title: storeData[i].title
                });
            }
        };
    </script>

</div>
```

---

**Problem**: In `initMap()` callback, you call `setMarkers(map)` only once. But inside the loop, you have more than one `setMarkers(map)` function. Then only the last `setMarkers(map)` function will be called by `initMap()` which displays the last store only.

**Solution**: The best solution is using [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to localize stores' data to a registered script:

You must do this at the beginning of the template:

```
$storeData = [];

foreach ($loop->posts as $post) {
    $storeData[] = [
        'title' => apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title),
        'lat'   => types_render_field('lat', array('output'=>'raw')),
        'long'  => types_render_field('long', array('output'=>'raw'))
    ];
}

wp_localize_script('jquery-core', 'storeData', $storeData);
```

Now, inside `initMap()` function, render each store data in `storeData` array:

```
for (var i=0; i<j; i++) {
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: storeData[i].lat, lng: storeData[i].long}),
        map: map,
        title: storeData[i].title
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could I just ask about the structure of the code and what to throw out? I am just not sure how to incorporate this into the current structure as it is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: I've tried this; but to no avail... (added to post)

Comment: @RuanPetersen I have just updated the answer.

Comment: Utter genius. Thank you. However this is still giving me a headache and I hate to make it yours but would you mind checking the console error on the page? I've had this error before but because of different reasons so I am not sure of the exact cause...

Comment: @RuanPetersen Well, The errors caused by `lat:` is not a valid value. You should change `lat:` and `lng:` to actual values. Update 2: I have done all jobs, just copy and paste the code in your template. It should work.

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank you so much!!! I only changed where the init map function starts and it works like a charm! I hope that we cross paths again and that I will be able to return the favour. Keep well my friend.

Comment: Please upvote the post for the next person.